# haskell how to transfer input type :String to Int

Tags: io

Here is the code for transferring the type: string to int

```
get_int :: IO Int
get_int = do num <-getLine
             return (read num :: Int)
```

But when I run it in GHCI, it shows me an error : Not in scope : 'num'. Perhaps you mean 'sum' 
why? 
and how to correct that code.
THANKS!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but I think has to do with ghci not supporting multiline expressions.

It works when compiled.

Try

```
get_int = do num <-getLine;return (read num :: Int)
```

in ghci